# Strange results when swapping items in Python list

Tags: python, list

When I try to swap 2 items in a list, some strange things happen. When trying this code, the nums is updated to `[4, 1, 3, 1]`:

```
i = 1
nums = [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[i]
nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1]
nums[i]
```

However, when the command is

```
nums[nums[i]-1]
nums[i] = nums[i]
nums[nums[i]-1]
```

The nums is `[-1, 1, 3, 4]`, which is what I expect.

I am totally confused about what happens in the two cases. Could anyone explain this clearly?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is called multiple assignment in Python.
Consider the following codes:

```
[print(0)][0], [print(1)][0] = print(2), print(3)
```

Outputs:

```
2
3
0
1
```

```
[print(0)][0] = [print(1)][0] = [print(2)][0] = [print(3)][0]
```

Outputs:

```
3
0
1
2
```

You might have found that for either of these assignments, the right-hand operands are evaluated first from left to right, and then it goes with left-hand operands.

It works the same way in the code you provided.

```
i = 1
nums = [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
```

In the right-hand side, `nums[nums[i]-1]` is evaluated to be `nums[3]`, which gives integer `1`, and then `nums[i]` is evaluated to be `nums[1]`, which gives integer 4.

Now it's the turn to assign values for the left-hand operands. At the moment, `nums[i]` refers to `nums[1]`, thus `1` is assigned to `nums[1]`. Note that `nums[1]` equals `1` now, and then the interpreter finds that `nums[nums[i]-1]` refers to `nums[1-1]` which is `nums[0]`! Then `4` is assigned to `nums[0]`, giving you the result `[4, 1, 3 ,1]`.

However, if you switch the operands, the order of this multiple assignment will change, and the result will be different. Similarily, the evaluation process is as follows:

```
nums: [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1]

nums: [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i] = 4, nums[nums[i]-1]

nums: [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i] = 4, 1

nums: [-1, 4, 3, 1]
nums[3], nums[i] = 4, 1

nums: [-1, 4, 3, 4]
nums[i] = 1

nums: [-1, 1, 3, 4]
```